# Настройка административного приложения django

Tags: django-admin, django

Добрый день. В админ. панели django при редактировании записи БД если в ней есть внешний ключ django выводит его как поле select со всеми возможными вариантами. Но если ключей становится много (в моём случае около 3-х миллионов) то это поле очень долго заполняется. Есть ли возможность подставить туда например поле ввода с авто-дополнением, или хотя бы ограничить кол-во ключей? Как вообще лучше поступить в этом случае? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть куча аутокомплитов, [сравнивай бери что нравится](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete/).
Так же в знаменитом [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) есть [ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/admin_extensions.html), должен тебя удовлетворить.

*ПС 3 миллиона? ты или сделал что-то не так или у тебя что-то большое.*

Comment: while True:
    db insert пока курю=)

Comment: rnd_d спасибо, обязательно изучу ваши ссылки. У меня в профиле пользователя есть внешний ключ на таблицу с городами, а там как раз примерно 3 миллиона городов планеты вот отсюда и проблемы. Вроде как тут других вариантов нет, или я ошибаюсь?
Я пока остановился на raw_id_fields, который обнаружился в стандартной поставке, авто дополнением займусь чуть позже.

Comment: о, заделись базой городов=)

Comment: Собственно база не моя а взята отсюда - http://www.geonames.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ну выход один: модифицировать админку под свои нужды... Какие существуют способы - многократно обсуждалось чуть ли не на каждом интернет ресурсе.

Comment: просто мне казалось что это распространённая проблема и возможно для неё есть решение. Ну если нет, то буду писать что то своё.